# Export XML file from SQL Server - NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK Service error

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

I've been trying to export the contents of an XML variable to a file on my disk from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) with the following command.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT @xml_file" queryout "C:\Radu\bcptest.txt" -T -c -t'
```

When running this command I'm constantly getting this error:

[image]

I've searched for answers and most of the things I found involved adding this `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` user to my database as a trusted user in SSMS, which would log in using Windows authentication, but this still didn't work.

[image]

I have also added roles as `bulkadmin` and `public` (in case of the user in Security->Logins path), `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter` and `public`, access to the `master` database which I am using (permission to connect, login), and also the same properties and permissions for the `DB_BULK_IMPORT_User`, but without success.

I've also changed in IIS the `Impersonation` of ASP .NET to enabled and restarted IIS server and the database server after each modification.

Is there something I'm missing? Or something I'm doing too much?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried running SSMS as admin? Is the error identical then?

Comment: @WimOmbelets Unfortunately it doesn't work, I just tried it. I get the same error.

Comment: you should run the profiler while executing this query and get somewhat more verbose feedback

Comment: @WimOmbelets Not quite. I've just tried it after your suggestion, but the only thing captured by the profiler is the queries, which I already know (can see)

Answer (score 1):

`-T` flag specifies that you are using a trusted connection using integrated security.  You may want to drop the `-T` and try specifying a username (`-U`) and password (`-P`).

Comment: Oh, sorry, it wasn't mentioned in the question...I'll delete it.

Comment: No problem. You can leave the answer. Maybe it will fix other people's issue.